# Is a desktop application possible using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js. I am curious, is it possible to program an interactive desktop application using node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, see [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), also there are plenty of modern apps that use node.js like popcorntime.

Here i left you a [good tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296) to start with node-webkit

Comment: can we deploy into .exe extension ??

Comment: Sure, see [How to Package and distribute - node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)